# SQL less than specific value between two columns

Tags: sql, where-in

I'm trying to make a statement to compare a specific value of '300' between the  following two columns:

- m02_bal_amount
- m01_bal_amount

How would I state that specific value between the two columns I would like to be less than?
i.e between the two columns listed above how can filter to show a difference of 300.

```
m02       m01
15        400
0         300
90        1000 



SELECT * FROM Database where data_pool = 0 and db_load_dt = '2012-01-10' and m02_bal_amount <= m01_bal_amount for fetch only with ur
```

Thanks very much

Comment: It is not clear what you are asking.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.

Comment: `300 between m02_bal_amount and m01_bal_amount` ?

Comment: Can you be more clear with your question

Comment: Question updated and yes 300 between the two amounts Imre

Answer (score 0):

<strike>Try BETWEEN</strike>

SELECT * FROM Database where data_pool = 0 and db_load_dt = '2012-01-10' 
    AND amount BETWEEN m02_bal_amount AND m01_bal_amount

I do't know your table schema. Try something like this

Update:

```
SELECT id, name, amount FROM 
(
    SELECT id, name, (m02_bal_amount - m01_bal_amount ) AS amount 
    WHERE 
    data_pool = 0 and 
    db_load_dt = '2012-01-10' 
) 
AS temp 
WHERE amount > 300
```

Comment: Trying to say amount between a specific value? in this case 300?

Comment: I am little confused..So you need to select data having m02-m01 < 300 ??

Comment: betwen m02 and m01 only return back if there is a difference of 300 or more